# adminimal theme tpl

Tags: 7, theming, emails

I'm having hard time with the inserting entity token to my mailchimp template.

1. Created a content type, newsletter, with title and body (long text and summary) fields.
2. Created a new view mode with display suite; mailchimp_body_summary (newz_body_summary) where I only display newsletter's body summary.

But when I insert the entity token with the new view mode, it still shows the title and contextual links with the body summary. I think I need to do something with the admin theme.

1. What would I call the tpl file? node--newsletter--newz_body_summary.tpl.php?
2. What would be in the tpl file?
3. Would I need to make changes anywhere else?